# Rails - changing displayed URL from the controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a page that has a form with one select list and a button.

```
<%= form_tag("/restaurant", method: "get") do %>
    <%= collection_select(:company_name, nil, Food.distinct_company_names, :company_name, :company_name) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search One", :name => nil, :class=>"btn btn-search") %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine to pass the parameters to my restaurant page, but I **don't** want the URL to display like this-

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurant?utf8=%E2%9C%93&company_name%5B%5D=McDonalds
```

I want it to display like this (my routes are setup to allow it)-

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurant/McDonalds
```

Here's my current solution in the controller...

```
def restaurant
if params[:company_name]
  @company_name = params[:company_name][0]
  redirect_to("/restaurant/"+@company_name)
else
 #avoid redirect loop
  @company_name ||= params[:id]
end
```

end

I'm thinking there's an easier or more elegant way to do this, though. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to change the url when the select changes value.  No need for the form.

```
<%= collection_select :company, :name, Food.distinct_company_names, :company_name, :company_name %>

<script>
  $('#company_name').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
      window.location = '/restaurant/' + $(this).val()
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I might go this route, seems cleaner. For whatever reason Rails made my collection_select ID "company_name_" so I just needed to tweak that. What if I wanted to have an entry in my select list that was a placeholder like "Select an option:"? If that gets selected I don't want it to try to navigate to that URL as it won't exist.

Comment: i've updated it so that it will only change the url if the selected option has a value.  the `id` of the select has an extra underscore because the second argument you passed is `nil`.  i split `company_name` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GET method you can use POST method to submit the form. Here you have to use restaurant controller and the action name is mcdonalds

```
<%= form_tag("/restaurant/mcdonalds", method: "post") do %>
<%= collection_select(:company_name, nil, Food.distinct_company_names, :company_name, :company_name) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search One", :name => nil, :class=>"btn btn-search") %>
```

in the routes.rb

```
post '/restaurant/mcdonalds'
```

Comment: the "mcdonalds" aspect isn't fixed; it's dynamic based on what is selected from the select list. So if the list has Subway, McDonalds, Taco Bell, etc. then it should route to /restaurant/Subway (or McDonalds, etc.) based on the select value.